# Duda sobre Maven, Gradle y Ant en proyectos con Netbeans 11.2

Tags: java, maven, gradle, ant, netbeans-11.2

Pensaba empezar a familiarizarme con netbeans 11.2 y me encuentro con diferentes "distribusiones" (no se como llamarles), para proyectos java quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre un proyecto **maven, gradle y ant.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si fuera posible, me explicaran para que sirve cada uno y si me dejaran referencias para documentarme mejor s elos agradeceria.

Comment: Si googleas Maven, Gradle y Ant obtendrás mucha información que te ayudará a entender que son. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven, Gradle y Ant son herramientas de automatización de la construcción de proyectos, básicamente se emplean para compilar proyectos.

Este artículo te los explica en detalle: https://www.baeldung.com/ant-maven-gradle

Y en esta pregunta de SO, se discute cual utilizar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163173/why-use-gradle-instead-of-ant-or-maven